# sharepoint 2013 sharepoint-hosted apps error 404

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am creating new apps on SharePoint2013 and adding them on a page of my site.  When I try running the apps it always gives me the following error:

> The resource cannot be found.  Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
> are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
> had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
> the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /***/Pages/Default.aspx"

I have looked for faults in IIS, eventviewer and logs and nothing is showing any fault. Where can I find what is causing this error?

Comment: Does your app contain Pages/Default.aspx page? Have you tried adding it?